# CDI Inject bean from outside

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Basically, my project is a war (MyProject) and imports 2 jars, MyProject-Client and MyProjectJar-API

MyProject

```
pom.xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
   <artifactId>MyProject-Client</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
   <artifactId>MyProjectJar-API</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

@Named
@Stateless
public class ParametroServiceImpl implements ParametroService, Serializable {
}
```

MyProjectJar-API - has one interface

```
public interface ParametroService {}
```

MyProject-Client - wants to inject ParametroService that is produces on MyProject

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RestEngine implements Serializable{
   @Inject
   private ParametroService parametroService;
}
```

I would like to know if its possible to inject ParametroService (Produced on MyProject) in MyProject-Client (that its a jar imported on  MyProject) ?

**UPDATE**

If I Inject in this way it does not work

```
@Inject
private ParametroService parametroService;
```

But if I do a programatically lookup it works, but I dont know why

```
BeanManager beanManager=(BeanManager)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
Bean<?> bean = beanManager.getBeans(ParametroService.class).iterator().next();
parametroService = (ParametroService)beanManager.getReference(bean, ParametroService.class, beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions: using `bean archives` or `@Producer` methods.

To turn your `MyProjectJar-API` into a bean archive, you just have to add a `META-INF` directory with a `beans.xml` inside. This is the preferable solution, if you control the jar you are using.

If you aren't able to modify the jar, you are still able to create a `@Producer` method, which creates an instance of the object. This method will be used by CDI to create the instance.

```
public class ParametroServiceProducer {
  @Produces
  public ParametroService createInstance() {
    return new ParametroServiceImpl();
  }
}
```